# Filling out a form contained in an iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, web-scraping

I need to make a chrome extension that fills out a form on a specific website automatically with some data a user has provided.

I've tried selecting the form elements by ID, class names and such but I'm always getting a null result (even though I can successfully select them from the browser console after the page has  loaded). To what I've read online it seems I can't access those elements with my content script because of security reasons.

Does anyone have an idea for how I can bypass this problem?

Comment: Perhaps open the iframe URL in a new window?

Comment: When I do that I seem to lose the submit button functionality